# Methods for delaying the "break" in non-linear least squares optimisation when the step size gets too small?

Tags: least-squares, optimization, algorithms, calibration, constrained-optimization

I am using the Levenberg-Marquardt method for calibration purposes. Typically, the RMSE of my calibration looks like:
[image]

I want to break the algorithm when the algorithm step-updates start to slow down, which is when the RMSE flat-lines at $\approx 150$. But the issue is at the start $\approx 1$ to $5$, the incremental steps also have very small and then it speeds up. So using a condition like $\lVert\frac{\Delta \theta_{t+t}}{\theta_t}\rVert <\epsilon$ when the steps are small also breaks the calibration at the start. Is there a robust method kinda like $\lVert\frac{\Delta \theta_{t+t}}{\theta_t}\rVert <\epsilon$ if ieration, $I >n$. But the $n$ has to be change for every different calibration because not very problem will have the calibration converging $\approx 150$.